# How to understand the Windows logging infomations?

Tags: windows, logging

I wrote a c# windows service which starts automatically, it's job will mainly delete some text file and modify the parent folder's last write time.
When this program did the job first time, this service stoped accidentally.
I check system's logging, but I can't position the bug code from the logging infomation.
So I need your help!Thanks very much !

These are the Exception infos , and the exception happened from .NET Runtime:

```
System.IO.IOException
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32, System.String)
at System.IO.FileStream.Init(System.String, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess, Int32, Boolean, System.IO.FileShare, Int32, System.IO.FileOptions, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(System.String, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess, System.IO.FileShare, Int32, System.IO.FileOptions, System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
at System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(System.String, Boolean, Boolean)
at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(System.String, Boolean, System.Text.Encoding, Int32, Boolean)
at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(System.String, Boolean, System.Text.Encoding)
at System.IO.File.InternalAppendAllText(System.String, System.String, System.Text.Encoding)
at WindowsService1.Service1+<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<Rec>b__0()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at WindowsService1.Service1+<Rec>d__5.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_1(System.Object)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```

20 seconds after the exception above, there is another error shows the error module path is C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll

Comment: The actual exception message is missing. But it's probably got something to do with files that are locked, or permissions.

Answer (score 0):

```
WindowsService1.Service1+<>c__DisplayClass5_0.b__0()
WindowsService1.Service1+d__5.MoveNext()
```

These two stack entries are actually your application’s code. BTW that’s why it’s a good idea to specify non-default names to the project, if you would name them `MyCompany.PreciousService` you would have noticed they are not from the runtime.

You probably have not written these `<>c__DisplayClass5_0` or `d__5` nested classes. C# compiler did. That’s what happens under the hood to async methods, or IEnumerable-returning methods implemented with `yield return`

The easiest way to make sense of the dump — keep `Service1.pdb` along with `Service1.exe`, at least in debug builds. You need them both built at the same time, can’t first build the .exe then use .pdb from another build, won’t match. Reproduce the problem, and you should see source file names and line numbers in the stack trace.